# Missing headers on CSV file

Tags: flask

Example file uploaded to flask:

```
account_id,account_name,style,graphic,color,size,team,player_name,player_num,upc,sku
12,Cleveland,C1394_ToddlerTrueClassicKnit NFL_S401ACY1,C1394_AZC,,OSFA,Arizona Cardinals,,,'12345',1234
12,Cleveland,C1394_ToddlerTrueClassicKnit NFL_S401ACY1,C1394_BBI,,OSFA,Buffalo Bills,,,'6789',5678
12,Cleveland,C1394_ToddlerTrueClassicKnit NFL_S401ACY1,C1394_CBE,,OSFA,Chicago Bears,,,'10111213',91011
```

The FileStorage object from `request.files` has somehow had the CSV header line removed.

Comment: Could you specify which part is specifically removed and show you know know that. I.e. show the code of you getting getting file's content from `request.files`.

Comment: @Vallentin I can't give you a screenshot, but the very first line (e.g. the headers) is not apart of the stream and is not in the iterable. It starts at row 2.

Comment: Do you have the form marked as `enctype=multipart/form-data` ?